# Can't convert a string to a customized one using f-Strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

I'm trying to create params using some values dynamically, so I tried to use f-Strings. However, i can't achieve what I expect to have.

If I use the following values:

```
lat = '13715482'
lon = '6320767'
some_id = '7783'
```

within the params below:

```
parameter = {'lat':f'{lat}','lon':f'{lon}','spatRef':{'spat_id':f'{some_id}'}}
```

I get output like:

```
{'lat': '13715482', 'lon': '6320767', 'spatRef': {'spat_id': '7783'}}
```

However, what I'm trying to get is (`notice the two double quotes around the whole string`):

```
"{'lat': '13715482', 'lon': '6320767', 'spatRef': {'spat_id': '7783'}}"
```

***How can I get that?***

Comment: Do you mean `import json; json.dumps(parameter)`?

Comment: Do you mean: `str(parameter)`?

Comment: @Psidom: Using `json` will do the exact opposite of the requirements: Put double quotes around the items and single quotes around everything.

Comment: @quamrana Sure, but I don't know how useful the format OP demanded can be. I thought he might just want to serialize it.

Comment: @Psidom: Fair point.

Comment: Both of your (Psidom and quamrana) suggestions worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're searching for [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)

```py
lat = '13715482'
lon = '6320767'
some_id = '7783'

parameter = str(
  {
    'lat': lat,
    'lon': lon,
    'spatRef': {
      'spat_id': some_id
    }
  }
)
```

To use this with quotes around it you could use this:

```py
print(f'{parameter!r}')
>>> "{'lat': '13715482', 'lon': '6320767', 'spatRef': {'spat_id': '7783'}}"
```

This uses the string's `__repr__`

Answer (score 1):

You need internal representation of the string that is printed and for that we can use the `repr` function.

```
lat = '13715482'
lon = '6320767'
some_id = '7783' 
parameter = {'lat':f'{lat}','lon':f'{lon}','spatRef':{'spat_id':f'{some_id}'}}
print(repr(str(parameter)))
```

OUTPUT

```
C:\Users\albin\Documents\codebase> python3 test.py
"{'lat': '13715482', 'lon': '6320767', 'spatRef': {'spat_id': '7783'}}"
```

Comment: Your suggested approach does print the expected output in the console. However, it doesn't work when I use the same within the parameters in a script. When I used `json.dumps()` or `str()`, I found them both working.

Comment: @SMTH I don't see what is your objective actually. The answer that you have marked as correct is exactly the same one that I wrote.

Comment: Please, don't misunderstand. It seems I should have been more specific about my objective. I was basically trying to issue a get http requests using that params. Give this a [check](https://pastebin.com/a6dKyp2a) to see how I used finally. Thanks.